# How to check length of an element in an array in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array suppose:

```
var myArray = [ "hello", "", "world", "!" ];
for ( var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i = i + 1 ) {
   console.log( myArray[ i ] );
}
```

I want to add like, if `myArray[i].length === 0`(empty element), don't do anything. I know length can't be used on array element but what's a subsitute?

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you use the length ?

Comment: Why would you want to use something else than .length to get the length of an array ? There is nothing faster and clearer.

Comment: You already know about `myArray.length" that's what you are looking for

Comment: put an `if` within the `for` to only post to console if it's not `""`

Comment: @Virus721 the goal is not to get the length of an array, but the length of an element of an array. Anyway, `length` seems perfectly fine in this case...

Comment: lol, the question is during console.log, i want to check if ````myArray[i]```` has some value (length > 0) otherwise dont write that entry in console. Now ````myArry[i].length > 0```` doesn't work so i am here for subsitute as i think there has to be a inbuilt method which does this

Comment: `if (myArray[i].length !== 0) console.log(myArray[i]);`

Comment: You can call `length` on both arrays and strings.

Answer (score 0):

Strings and Arrays share the same length property.

```
var myArray = [ "hello", "", "world", "!" ];
for ( var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i = i + 1 ) {
   console.log( myArray[ i ].length ); // will give you the length of the string
}
```

if the string is empty `myArray[ i ].length` will return 0

Answer (score 0):

About 'How to check length of an element in an array with jQuery'

[jQuery.length()](http://api.jquery.com/length/)

[i found it here, straight forward on google](https://www.google.ca/#q=How%20to%20check%20length%20of%20an%20element%20in%20an%20array%20in%20jQuery)